# Why did Kronecker say "the integers are the work of God, the rest is the work of man"?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

To me, it seems no number is the work of God, they are all concepts of the mind.

However, it seems negative numbers are more artificial than the rest of the numbers out there. So why did he describe them as part of god's work?

Thank you.

Comment: Because at the time when Kronecker said this, there was no more basic theory in terms of which integers could be defined. Nowadays we have such a theory; it is called set theory.